# Pass email to mailchimp unsubscribe link

Tags: mailchimp

I have an unsubscribe link that looks like this:

`example.com/unsubscribe?u=foo&id=bar`

This loads the typical mailchimp unsubscribe form. Is it possible to have the email address pre-populated somehow? Perhaps by adding the email in some query string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add the parameter on the end of the URL

`&EMAIL=user@domain.co.uk`

Comment: Don't do this. Some mail providers will obfuscate the address when the recipient clicks on the link, so the query string wil lbe incorrect.